# Debug iOS browser tools?

Tags: ios, laravel

How can I debug Safari or Chome on iOS 11?

I have a Laravel web-app that accepts image uploads. It fails on mobile but the same original image works on laptop. I am extracting GPS coordinates from each image and have an exit message if a key is not found. On laptop its there but on mobile it's not. How can I inspect what's going on?

Comment: Think [this](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787) is what you need

Comment: I can get it working on safari thanks for that, but would prefer on chrome